# Adobe Marketing Cloud Visitor ID on Cross domain tracking?

Tags: adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

Will AMC Visitor ID service really helps to track cross domain tracking? or should i need to go with FPC in order to do cross domain tracking. My scenario is below...

```
Want to track Domain A --> Domain B(FPC already available: metrics.domainA.com)
New requirement: Domain C  --> Domain D(Not sure if we need seperate FPC(ie: metrics.domainc.com)
```

Also, in future i can expect this requirement Domain A --> Domain C --> Domain D

not sure, if i use Visitor ID will there be any chances of browser rejecting third party cookies. Because, Adobe is still recommending to go with CNAME(FPC) if we are collecting data from multiple domains.

https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mcvid/visid_mig_overview.html
https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mcvid/mcvid_cname.html

Any suggestion??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to start out by saying that neither the Visitor ID service nor the FPC implementation is a perfect solution for cross-domain tracking. Long story short is there will always be limitations because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), as well as how different browsers treat cookies via default security settings and what visitors can do to alter those settings (particularly IE and Safari).

Having said that, if you have a DomainA that is a common portal to your other domains, [you could benefit from implementing **both**](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mcvid/mcvid_cname.html). But if there is no common/sole entry point, there is no real advantage to doing one over the other from a tracking PoV, but the Visitor ID service will be easier and less expensive to implement and maintain.

On a sidenote, it's worth mentioning this as an alternative: You could always write some code to generate your own visitorid and then pass it to each domain via URL params (This is how Google Analytics handles cross-domain tracking).

On paper, this is theoretically the best option because it completely removes 3rd party cookies and 1st-party-in-3rd-party-context from the equation. In reality though, it's generally a lot harder to implement 100%.

If all the links on all your sites are 100% standard and generated and output from server (no dynamic generation from js or added after page load) then it's fairly easy to implement. But in reality, most sites have a lot of dynamically generated content, links that aren't directly pointing to other sites (goes through other code first), etc. so it becomes hard if not feasible to make it 100%, despite the fact that it is in your hands to do it.

Having said all that.. there's no real benefit to NOT doing any of these. The alternative is to continue with the default 3rd party tracking implementation and that has more of a chance of rejection than all the other options.

**TL;DR:** Currently there is no perfect cross-domain solution for web analytics tracking. This is one of many reasons why it is important to look at trends in your data, not just raw numbers.